# When Using Stripe CLI to Trigger payment_intent.succeeded, No Email Is Generated: How To Test?

Tags: stripe-payments

Per the recommendations in the official Stripe documentation, I have been using the Stripe CLI to test my integration before going live. The integration is simple, all I do is collect payments and a customer email address, but the email address is essential because it's what I use to create a customer account (which will, in many cases, only be created *after* payment.) It's also a required field on the payment form.

When I run the following command in a terminal:

```
~$ stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
```

It correctly triggers the event, and my webhook script is notified, and it correctly receives and processes the event. However, the event data that is being generated in this manner does not contain an email address, not even a test or fake one. When I looked through the output of `var_export()` on the event object, the `'email'` field occurred 11 times in the object, yet it was `NULL` every time.

This is not useful for me to test the project. It's not clear to me, with real data, where the customer field will appear and/or if some of these other fields will still be NULL.

Is there any way I can generate such an event but with a test email as if the user had filled out the (required) field on the payment form?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say since you didn't provide code or more specific details, but it sounds like you're creating [a Customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers) in Stripe and setting [the `email` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-email) on that object, then creating [a Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) to charge that Customer.

If that's the case the `payment_intent.succeeded` event will contain the Payment Intent object, not the Customer object, which explains why you're not seeing the `email` property you set on the Customer object.  [The Payment Intent object does have a `customer` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-customer) though, and it will be set to the ID of the Customer associated with it.  You can use that ID to [fetch the Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve) and obtain their `email` that way.

Alternatively, you can add the email address directly to the Payment Intent using [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata).

Comment: I don't know what Stripe is doing behind the scenes when I run `stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded`, nor can I find documentation on it. So not sure how I could provide more details. It does return a customer ID, so I suppose I could fetch it that way, but this seems an unnecessary path to go down. I was trying to use the CLI (as instructed in docs) to test my integration before going live but it doesn't seem to be generating the same sorts of data or results as my form. What I really want is to be able to access the email specified in the payment form so maybe I need to ditch the CLI.

Comment: Yeah, if you want data specific to your form you need to use your form in test mode.  The `stripe trigger` command performs operations to trigger the specified event, but those operations are defined ahead of time and are not based on your specific integration or data.

Answer (score 0):

Now that my integration is mostly done and tested, in hindsight, I found the Stripe CLI useless and unnecessary, and I wished their documentation hadn't emphasized it so heavily. Similarly, the dashboard tools for generating test events were not useful either.

As Justin Michael suggested above in his comment, the most important thing was to use my form in test mode. This generated test data of the sort that my integration would generate in live mode. I was then able to test any emails generated by my server, myself.

For the emails generated on Stripe's end, their dashboard had tools to generate test emails, under Branding -> Email Recepits.